# Xcode xib editor not loading

Tags: xcode, xib

Running Xcode 13.2.1 in Monterey 12.2.1

I have an Objective-C project where Xcode will suddenly not open an editor for the xib files. If I double click them in the finder *with the project NOT open*, they open in the editor. The project file also only opens as text.

Other Swift projects are fine.

The app will still build and run but I cannot make interface changes!

Previous suggestions about copying xib files etc have not helped. Restart and reboots have also not helped.

Suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a solution to this over in apple developer discussions from 4 years ago!

The solution was to open the xib file in an assistant editor. Once one is opened correctly, all the subsequent xib files open correctly.